# Xerces + Python?

Tags: python, xml, xslt, xpath, xerces

Does anyone know if there's an available python library compatible with Python2.6 that exposes the Xerces functionality and its XML DOM capabilities?

I would define the desired capabilities as: XML DOM select by Xpath & XSLT processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pirxx](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pirxx/) in theory could match your requirements, but it hasn't been maintained in several years so I'd expect some minor incompatibilities with 2.6 to be likely to show up.  However, it might still be worth your while to try it -- perhaps fixing those minor things (if they're indeed minor!) and contributing the fixes upstream (or forking the project if upstream should prove to be totally comatose) might be less work than starting from scratch (which is the only other option I'm aware of).

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean.  Thanks for the recommendation!